# Overriding a generic method with void type T in swift causes the compiler to seg fault

Tags: swift

Given:

```
class MyGenericSuperClass<T> {
    func randomMethod(param:T) {
      print("SuperClass")            
    }
}

class MyGenericSubClass : MyGenericSuperClass<Void> {
    override func randomMethod(param:Void) {
      print("SubClass")
    }
}
```

The following will compile:

```
class test {
  init() {
      let test1 = MyGenericSuperClass<Void>()
      test1.randomMethod() // outputs 'SubClass'

      let test2:MyGenericSuperClass<Void> = MyGenericSubClass()
      test2.randomMethod() // outputs 'SubClass'
  }
```

}

But this causes a segmentation fault 11:

```
class test {
    init() {
        let test2 = MyGenericSubClass()
        test2.randomMethod()
    }
}
```

The only difference is the storing of the subclass in a super class variable.

Is this a compiler bug or is there something else at play here?

**Background:**
This was coming from a `Command<TArg>` class with an `ActionCommand : Command<Void>` subclass and then MySpecificActionCommand subclass

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not properly overriding randomMethod. It should be:

```
class MyGenericSubClass<T> : MyGenericSuperClass<Void> {
    override func randomMethod(param:Void) {
        print("SubClass")
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell this should work, so I'm guessing it's a bug. Messing around a bit, it seems to be due to `MyGenericSuperClass<Void>`. If you change it to something else, e.g. `MyGenericSuperClass<String>` everything works properly.

Comment: Yes I'd just noticed (after the first answer) that I'd typed that out wrong (T instead of Void) - have corrected in the question

Comment: It's a bit of a weird one because `randomMethod(param:Void)` is a bit meaningless but it satisfies a generic that's indicating that the param can be anything including nothing

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Void?

Comment: it was for a Command (or if you prefer FunctionObject) type object that exposes an 'execute' that takes varying params depending on the generic implementation.  Void would indicate no param at all.  Could be separate protocols one with execute and one with execute(T) but then they wouldn't be of the same type (for some shared code within the heirarchy and for things like extensions etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `MyGenericSubClass` like this to work properly.

```
class MyGenericSubClass<T> : MyGenericSuperClass<T> {
    override func randomMethod(param:T) {
        print("SubClass")
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed it isn't specifying the T in the superclass like my example.  To make it clearer I'll remove the generic on the subclass completely in the example

Comment: Right, but you're now linking the two types together, rather than being of the type of MyGenericSuperClass<Void>